# How create dynamic generated dropdown in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a table `statuses` (columns `id`, `statusename`) and want display a "select" list based by this table dynamically.
My model:

```
namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Statuses extends Model
    {
       protected $table = "CaseStatus";
    }
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Statuses;
class StatusesList extends Controller
{
    public function getstatuseslist() {
        $list = Statuses::all();
        return view('forms.statuses')->with('data', $list);
    }
}
```

`statuses.blade.php`:

```
<select name="Statuses">
@foreach ($data as $page)
<option value="{{ $page->ID }}">{{ $page->StatuseName }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Route:

```
Route::any('/list/statuses','StatusesList@getstatuseslist');
```

If i'm open url http://myproject/list/statuses - it work fine, i see the dropdown list.
But if I include my `statuses.blade.php` in a form in another template:

```
 @include('forms.statuses')
```

I get the error

```
"Undefined variable data".
```

How to include it correctly?
My Laravel version is 5.4.

Comment: where you had put  @include('forms.statuses') , i mean in which .blade file?

Comment: i'm include it in my views\forms\dialog-mainform.blade.php

Comment: in that case you need to call  return view('forms.dialog-mainform')->with('data', $list);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all models are meant to get raw's and not tables if you have table `statuses` your model name should be `status`.

the issue of your function not working in another blade is because your another blade controller does not connected to your model so it doesn't know where to get info that you asking for. to solve that issue it's easy, just add your model codes this->

```
public function getstatuseslist() {
        $list = Statuses::all();
        return view('your_other_view')->with('data', $list);
    }
```

into that page controller.

don't forget to call your model in your second controller as well.

```
use App\Statuses;
```

after that will work just fine in your second blade also.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$data` is passed to your `'forms.statuses'` view only, when it's pass from that controller method you defined.

If you want to use this data for other "parent" views that include `'forms.statuses'`, you have to pass it again in the controller that returns that 'parent' view.

There's a way you can make it persist in many views. See 'view composer' for details. Here's the link to view composers at Laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers